# Flutter project deployment on vercel

Tags: flutter, deployment, vercel

I've deployed flutter project on vercel from github, but after deployment it shows:

> 404: NOT_FOUND Code: NOT_FOUND.
> Framework presets: Others

Build log:

> 15:28:18.542      Cloning github.com/Usman167/UPKeepApp-FluxStore- (Branch: master, Commit: e331f69)
> 15:28:20.977    Cloning completed: 2.435s
> 15:28:21.169    Analyzing source code...
> 15:28:26.899    Uploading build outputs...
> 15:28:26.913    Deploying build outputs...
> 15:28:33.974    Done with "."

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can change your Vercel project settings to build and deploy a Flutter Web project.

#### Build & Development Settings

- Framework Preset: `Other`
- Build Command: `flutter/bin/flutter build web --release`
- Output Directory: `build/web`
- Install Command: `if cd flutter; then git pull && cd .. ; else git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git; fi && ls && flutter/bin/flutter doctor && flutter/bin/flutter clean && flutter/bin/flutter config --enable-web`

[image: Screenshot of Vercel Build Settings for Flutter]

Example build log showing a successful Flutter deploy

[image: Screenshot of Vercel Build Log for Flutter]

Comment: Do you know how I can checkout a specific version of flutter? Because wtih some versions the build is failing due to null safety not working(enforced??)

e.G. if I want to use flutter version 2.2.3

Comment: Solution:

you can just use "git checkout 2.2.3" to use a specific version.

Example of my bash script:

`#!/bin/bash

if cd flutter; then git pull && cd .. ; else git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable; fi && ls && cd flutter && git checkout 2.2.3 && cd .. && flutter/bin/flutter doctor && flutter/bin/flutter clean && flutter/bin/flutter pub get



`

Comment: I'm getting the error `Error: The 'super-parameters' language feature is disabled for this library.`. Any idea?

Comment: I fixed my issue by updating the flutter version, updating all packages and setting the SDK to `">=2.17.0 <3.0.0"`

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1

run the command in the root of  project:`flutter build web`
[image: build the flutter web by run the command in the root of the project:flutter build web]

create new repository in github and upload the web folder to github
[image]

and follow the procedure in below figure in vercel
[image]

https://githubactionss.vercel.app/#/
https://github.com/lavahasif/githubaction

### Method 2

Just Create Flutter template project(test)

```
flutter create -t skeleton my_app
```

[image]
verify the web folder (enable web) exist other wise vercel show error
[image]
upload the entire project to github
do like this
[image]

- Build Command: `flutter/bin/flutter build web --release`
- Output Directory: `build/web`
- Install Command: `if cd flutter; then git pull && cd .. ; else git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git; fi && ls && flutter/bin/flutter doctor && flutter/bin/flutter clean && flutter/bin/flutter config --enable-web`

and Finally just deploy
the link like this
https://web-my-app.vercel.app/#/

Comment: Bro can You guide me about flutter Mobile app project.

Comment: I think you want to host your flutter project as website in vercel.isn't it?.

Comment: bro actually i'm using stripe payment gateway in my flutter mobile app. For that i've deployed it on vercel. but it shows this error.

Comment: https://fidev.io/stripe-checkout-in-flutter-web/. did you tried this

Comment: https://itnext.io/flutter-web-razorpay-payment-gateway-integration-792d6e015409